# Beats per minute counter using key presses in C

Tags: c, keypress

I'm building a C program to determine how many times a key is pressed in one minute (think "beats per minute") so I can use it later in a metronome I'm building.

I want to build something like [this](http://www.all8.com/tools/bpm.htm) in C. How would I read the key presses as they happen?

Comment: Are we talking about holding down a key and determining the repeat rate?

Comment: @user3386109 i want it to work as the one on the link. ill keep pressing space key (for example) and the program determinates how many times i do it in one minute

Comment: What exactly is "the key press problem"? You don't know how to read key presses? Don't know how to count key presses? etc?

Comment: @AlanAu i dont know who to read the key press othe ther scanf and gets functions. im using ubuntu 15.04

Comment: If you use the `Enter` key you can use `gets`. ;-)

Comment: @dlask and use another character to exit the loop?

Comment: You can exit the loop using a character followed by `Enter`, or simply by pressing `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: That program you linked is pretty naive.  Most BPM tap-tempo algorithms use a window of about 4 presses.  All you need to do is keep the times of the last four key presses and average them.  There are countless examples of how to request the time in C, just a web-search away.

Comment: Getting keypresses is surprisingly difficult in C.  Either write your program to just detect the enter key, or look up the ncurses library for linux.

Comment: @paddy, I did, found a lot of examples. thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`fgetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetc.html) to read keypress of the ENTER key.

Use [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gettimeofday.html) to measure time in microseconds, compute time elapsed from previous keypress, and divide 60s by it.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval t0, t1;
    float elapsed;
    gettimeofday(&t0, 0);
    while(1) {
        fgetc(stdin);
        gettimeofday(&t1, 0);
        elapsed = (t1.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) * 1000.0f + (t1.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec) / 1000.0f;
        memcpy(&t0, &t1, sizeof(struct timeval));
        printf("%f\n", 60000./elapsed);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to average displayed values (e.g. keep a running average) to reduce variance.

Comment: This worked! I'll add some more conditions to get what I need from here. Thanks for the help :)